# Best way to select all records

Tags: sql

Does anyone know a performance or any other benefit of using select(1) or select(*) over the other? I am looking to optimize searching

Comment: Not sure what you mean but selecting more fields degrades performance.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/

Comment: `select(1)`?  In what SQL dialect does `select(1) from table` *not* give a single column with a `1` for each row of `table`?

Comment: well the two queries perform very different things, so I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to compare `SELECT COUNT(1)` vs. `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT(1) FROM X WHERE P = Q)` is one use of `SELECT 1`

Comment: As far as I know it is always better to declare all the columns instead the *, because at compile you know the columns, when you use the *, the RDMS have to look the columns and then execute the query and it obviously affect the performance, thas that someone teached me, i haven't done a research about it, but it makes somesense

Comment: @Mr, the OP is probably talking about a point at which the column(s) returned is arbitrary, such as in my example above.

Comment: @Justin Oh okay, i was answering abot the subject of the questing, "Best way to select all records" I supposed that how to get all the records. Thats the why of my answer, but as I see in your related post, there is no such difference o.o, strange thing, in my opinion I would say it is obviously better select 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some instances it makes a difference...The best thing to do is to look at the execution plan for your query using SELECT (1) and SELECT (*)

This post is also a good resource:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/

Answer (score 1):

select 1 will transmit less data, so technically it's faster.  Not sure how useful it is though.

Comment: when using 'where exists (select 1 ....)  it is very useful. Also in case you need a dummy field to compare in combination with a union: select name, spend from table1 union name, 0 from table2